# Find all metrics on a set $X$ consisting of two points. Consisting of one point.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

First, this is an exercise in the first section of Kreyszig's introductory functional analysis text. In this section he has already given several examples of metric spaces, including: $l^\infty$, $C[a,b]$, and an example of a discrete metric space. In this section he has stated that we can interpret things like infinite but bounded sequences (for $l^\infty$) as points, or continuous functions on closed intervals (for $C[a,b]$) as points. So, I think I should interpret this question as all possible metrics for any type of abstract set $X$, which only has two things--points--in it.

---

**Attempt:**

No matter what the set $X$ considered is, as long as the metric $d$ defined on $X$ is maps $(x,y) \in X \times X$ to the nonnegative real numbers, (not including $+ \infty$), maps zero to zero, *and* is a non-affine function of $(x-y)$ it will suffice as a metric. ...

...all of these assumptions I'm making will just build to the definition of a metric it seems like.

---

Maybe the author means a traditional set of points, i.e., finite tuples? I think I'm missing the spirit of the question.

Comment: Let $X=\{x,y\}$.  What is $d(x,x)$?  What could $d(x,y)$ be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've given a description of a metric (though it's not quite correct), but you haven't described specifically what a metric on a space consisting of two points could be.

Suppose $X=\{a,b\}$. As you stated, the metric must give a value to $d(x,y)$ for every $(x,y) \in X \times X$. In other words, you need to specify $d(a,a), d(a,b),d(b,a)$, and $d(b,b)$. How much choice do you have for these values?

Your description of a metric is not quite correct for a few reasons. You say it must "map zero to zero," but the metric is a function of points $(x,y) \in X \times X$, so what you really mean is it maps points of the form $(x,x)$ to zero. You also say it must be a non-affine function of $(x-y)$, but it is clearer and more correct to say that if $x \neq y$ then $d(x,y)\neq 0$. Finally, your description is not sufficient to define a metric, because a metric must also be symmetric: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I think I see. Is the author's question hinting toward the way we define a discrete metric space? All we need is $d(x,y) = c > 0$ for $x \neq y$ and $d(x,x) = 0$ for $x \in X$. Furthermore, for a single point, I think all we'd need is $d(x,x) = 0$.

Comment: You need $d(x,y)=c>0$ for $x \neq y$, *and* $d(y,x)=...$?

Comment: I didn't include $d(y,x) = c$ just because it's part the normal definition of a metric (in my text).

Comment: Right, but it's important to note. If you just say you need to choose a positive value for $d(x,y)$ for each $x \neq y$, then it does not necessarily follow that the value you chose for $d(x,y)$ is the same as the value you chose for $d(y,x)$. But to have a metric, they must be the same value.

Answer (score -1):

If $X$ has only two points, then the triangle inequality property is a
consequence of ($M1$) to ($M3$). Thus, any functions satisfy ($M1$) to ($M3$) is a
metric on $X$. If $X$ has only one point, say, $x_0$, then the symmetry and triangle
inequality property are both trivial. However, since we require $d(x_0, x_0) = 0$, any
nonnegative function $f(x, y)$ such that $f(x_0, x_0) = 0$ is a metric on $X$.

Comment: Solution: If X has only two points, then the triangle inequality property is a
consequence of (M1) to (M3). Thus, any functions satisfy (M1) to (M3) is a
metric on X. If X has only one point, say, x0, then the symmetry and triangle
inequality property are both trivial. However, since we require d(x0, x0) = 0, any
nonnegative function f(x, y) such that f(x0, x0) = 0 is a metric on X.